# How to make games that use graphic instead of text?

Tags: python, text, graphics

Hi I was wondering if anyone could answer my question, how would I go about making a game with graphics in python instead of text based games.
I'm only new though so if it involves another programming language then I'm probably can't do it yet.

Comment: Search on google

Comment: Have a look at https://www.pygame.org/

Comment: Had a look at that earlier, seems good. @sal Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the tkinter library. You can makes games with graphics instead of text. One example would be [here](http://www.bitforestinfo.com/2017/01/how-to-create-snake-game-using-python.html). And it is just Python :)

Answer (score 1):

Use tkinter module inside of python. To do this simply add `from tkinter import *` at the start of your program and open a window and use a mainloop to close it at the end. You can research how to use tkinter online on various different websites. I would suggest effbot as it's very useful for tkinter basics.